# What does "hopefully" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech

In the following sentence, what does *hopefully* mean, what part of speech is it, and what does it modify?

> Hopefully the rain will end soon.

From http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hopefully:

> 1 : in a hopeful manner
>   2 : it is hoped : I hope : we hope : hopefully the rain will end soon

It must be #2 according to the example.  If it means "it is hoped" or "I hope" then is the entire main subject and predicate of the sentence subsumed into the word *hopefully*?

A related question is, if I use a comma, how does that change the sentence grammatically and semantically?

> Hopefully, the rain will end soon.

Comment: What dictionaries have you looked at?

Comment: I'm not sure about the terminologies used by modern grammars of English (especially generative and functional ones). Traditionally, it would be an *adverb*. It could be considered that it modifies the whole sentence, but I believe that it is traditionally considered to modify the verb of the main clause. As for the meaning, I couldn't describe it better than any dictionaries either. Though in my opinion, "hopefully" could be understood as "hope-full-like", i.e. "in a manner that is full of hope".

Comment: @user8543, good point.  Question updated.

Comment: @DamkerngT. FYI, question has been updated and slightly changed.

Answer (score 5):

*Hopefully* is an adverb in your excerpt, but it modifies the entire sentence rather than any individual word within it. It is an example of a *disjunct*, about which Brinton & Brinton (via [LinguisticsGirl](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/linguistic-definition-of-disjunct-adverbial/)) say

> Disjunct adverbials denote the attitude of the speaker toward or judgment of the proposition such as truthfulness of manner of speaking. …
> The grammatical forms that can function as the disjunct adverbial in English grammar are the adverb phrase, prepositional phrase, and adverb clause.

More specifically, it is a *[sentence adverb](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sentence-adverb)*, a common if sometimes disliked usage:

> Unfortunately, the show ended late.
>
> Thankfully, the kitchen is still open.
>
> Obviously, we will order both desserts.

[Oxford reports general suspicion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hopefully#hopefully__7) of sentence adverbs in some quarters; some prefer to reword them— *it is lucky that* in place of *luckily*— and reject those which refer to the speaker's attitude, which cannot be reworded in this way (one cannot say *it is frank that* in place of *frankly*). That seems quite arbitrary, however. Clearly, such usage is widely accepted, and hopefully, you will not get caught up by misguided purists.